# Auth issue with Smartedit in combination with EarlyLogin

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In our current B2B project, we need to use the EarlyLogin functionality together with Smartedit.
Unfortunately, the EarlyLogin prevents a smartedit user from accessing the FrontEnd, after Login into smartedit. 
Obviously, because the smartedit user does not have an access token to spartacus yet.

Did someone already resolve that issue and how would you do that?

We are thinking about sending two auth requests, one for smartedit and an additional login request for spartacus with maybe a dummy customer.

Or is there a better work around?

Any help is appreciated :)

Many thanks in advance,
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a dummy customer in Spartacus. Then smartedit user can login as this dummy user in Spartacus.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot of for your answer, Weizhang.

Ideally, a smartEdit user should not be forced to login twice.
Plus, we face a lot of issues with smartEdit in combination with an unauthenticated  customer in an protected storefront environment.

Anyhow, that will be our work around as well. We do send an authorization request with a dummy customer for the Spartacus storefront, once the SmartEdit user logs in to SmartEdit.